# Angular Checkbox Filter with Paginator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I'm using this AngularJS paginator, https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination.
And I'm also using the example in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tASrOwMSfcg) to add checkbox filters to my ng-repeat. I want to filter based on whether the `specie` property of every `animal` object (animal.specie) is a `cat` or a `dog`. I start setting both to true but my ng-repeat doesn't populate when I do that. And when I check a box to `true` or `false` nothing happens.

The only thing in the controller is `$scope.species = {dogs: true, cats: true};`

What is wrong with my implementation? Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

```
    <div class="row adopt-title-wrap">
    <div class="medium-6 large-6 column">
        <h3>Find Your Next Best Friend</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-2 large-2 end column">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="species.cats">
        <label>Cats Only</label>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-2 large-2 end column">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="species.dogs">
        <label>Dogs Only</label>
    </div>
</div><br>

<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x"></i>

<div class="row">
    <!-- Start Single Animal Record -->
    <div class="medium-6 large-6 end column" dir-paginate="animal in animals
                                                        | filter: {specie: 'Dog'} : species.dogs
                                                        | filter: {specie: 'Cat'} : species.cats
                                                        | itemsPerPage: 6">
        <div class="panel">
            <img class="pet-img" ng-src="{{ animal.profile_photo }}" alt="pet for adoption">
            <ul class="pet-details">
                <li class="pet-field-title">Name</li>
                <li class="pet-field-value">{{ animal.name }}</li>
                <li class="pet-field-title">Age</li>
                <li class="pet-field-value">{{ animal.dob }}</li>
                <li class="pet-field-title">Breed</li>
                <li class="pet-field-value">{{ animal.breed }}</li>
                <li class="pet-field-title">Code</li>
                <li class="pet-field-value">{{ animal.shelter_code }}</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="pet-description">{{ animal.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End Single Animal Record -->
</div>

<dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just learned that Angular filters don't have (at least not yet) the functionality I was looking for. So I worked around the issue by changing the check boxes to radio buttons and make a different backend API call based on the radio selected.

template:

```
    <div class="row adopt-title-wrap">
    <div class="medium-5 large-5 column">
        <h4>Find Your Next Best Friend!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-1 large-1 column">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-2 large-2 column">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="species" value="all">
        <label>Show All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-2 large-2 column">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="species" value="cats">
        <label>Cats Only</label>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-2 large-2 column end">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="species" value="dogs">
        <label>Dogs Only</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <!-- Start Single Animal Record -->
    <div class="single-record medium-6 large-6 end column" dir-paginate="animal in animals | itemsPerPage: 6">
        <div class="panel">
            <img class="pet-img" ng-src="{{ animal.profile_photo }}" alt="pet for adoption">
            <ul class="pet-details">
                <li class="pet-field-title">Name</li>
                <li class="pet-field-value">{{ animal.name }} ({{animal.specie }})</li>


             <li class="pet-field-title">Age</li>
                <li class="pet-field-value">{{ animal.dob }}</li>
                <li class="pet-field-title">Breed</li>
                <li class="pet-field-value">{{ animal.breed }}</li>
                <li class="pet-field-title">Code</li>
                <li class="pet-field-value">{{ animal.shelter_code }}</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="pet-description">{{ animal.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End Single Animal Record -->
</div>

<dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
```

Controller:

```
    angular.module('animalShelterApp')
.controller('AdoptCtrl', function ($scope, SharedServices) {

    var spinner = angular.element('.fa-spinner'); // Holds spinner element.

    /*
    * Binds 3 radio buttons (all, cats, dogs).
    * Load 'all' records by default.
    */
    $scope.species = 'all';

    /*
    * When user selects a specie, display appropriate data.
    */
    $scope.$watch('species', function() {
        spinner.show();

        if ($scope.species === 'all') {
            /*
            * Get all available animals.
            */
            SharedServices.getAllAnimals().success(function(data) {
                spinner.hide();
                $scope.animals = data;
            });

        } else if ($scope.species === 'cats') {
            /*
            * Get all available Cats.
            */
            SharedServices.getAllCats().success(function(data) {
                spinner.hide();
                $scope.animals = data;
            });

        } else if ($scope.species === 'dogs') {
            /*
            * Get all available Dogs.
            */
            SharedServices.getAllDogs().success(function(data) {
                spinner.hide();
                $scope.animals = data;
            });
        }

    }); // end $scope.$watch('species').

}); // end AdoptCtrl.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend stripping down your code to the base, maybe just get everything displayed and then migrate to pagination. I can spot your first issue is you are applying two filters on specie.

```
dir-paginate="animal in animals | filter: {specie: 'dog'} | filter: {specie: 'cat'}"
```

is basically saying filter down to animals that are **both** a dog **and** a cat. The first filter will return an array of only dogs, then the second filter will run on that finding only cats, which is none because obviously you can't be a dog and a cat :)

```
Original Array: [{name: 'bob', specie: 'cat'}, {name: 'jeff', specie: 'dog'}] | filter dogs | filter cats
After First Filter (only dogs): [{name: 'jeff', specie: 'dog'}] | filter cats 
After Second Filter (only animals that are both dogs and cats): []
```

Try defining your own angular filter to simplify your work as so:

```
.filter('isCatOrDog', function() {
    return function(inputAnimals) {
       return inputAnimals.filter(function(animal) {
          return animal.value === 'cat' || animal.value === 'dog';
       });
    }
});
```

And you call the filter as so:

```
dir-paginate="animal in animals | isCatOrDog"
```

[Basic Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aqQtmBxkkmVLSVv5Kc7S?p=preview)